# Python looping through two sets to compare all elements of each set

Tags: python, set

I am attempting to write a function that when given a set of Country names and a set of State names will compare the two sets to see if there is at least one country and one state that start with the same three letters.

I have tried many different ways to do this from creating a new set containing the first three letters of all the state and country names but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    def StartsWithSameThreeLetters(x,y):
        common = set(state[:3] for state in x) and set(country[:3] for country in y)
        length = len(x) + len(y)
        if length != len(common):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

if x is the set of state names and y is the set of country names

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: I have tried using for loops to loop through each element of the sets and compare the first three letters of each element and I have tried making sets containing the first three letters of all the country and state names and comparing those

Comment: Please post your code.  Looping should have easily worked, it's just 2 `for` loops with a `state[:3] == country[:3]` check.

Comment: I just posted my code above in my most recent attempt to make the function work

Comment: `set1 and set2` isn't the same as `set1 & set2`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use set comprehensions:

```
common = {country[:3] for country in countries} & {state[:3] for state in states}
```

If your Python installation is too old to use them, there's always `set()`:

```
set(country[:3] for country in countries)
```